# Do I need to add Content-Type header if I already set the StringEntity's content type?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to do a POST request against a server with a UTF-8 JSON in the body:

```
public HttpRequest createRequest() {
    HttpPost req = new HttpPost(API_URL);
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(notification.toString(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));         
    stringEntity.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
    req.setEntity(stringEntity);
    return req;
}
```

Are stringEntity's content type and charset added automatically to the request?

Or do I have to add the header to `req`?

```
req.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: no, you do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not. Content metadata headers are generated automatically by [RequestContent](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/4.4.x/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/protocol/RequestContent.java) protocol interceptor.